On GKE with Workload Identity, is it possible to specify the K8s Service Account?
In a GKE Pod using Workload Identity, as far as I can tell, only the Pod's Service Account (from the PodSpec.serviceAccountName property) is used. Presumably, by using /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/.
If we mount a ServiceAccount Token Secret, mount a ServiceAccountToken projected volume, or call the TokenRequest API directly we can get a hold of an arbitrary ServiceAccount's credentials. Is it possible to use these ServiceAccount credentials with GKE Workload Identity?
Why?: We have a multi-user system and want to avoid users storing long-lived keys on the system. We populate individual ServiceAccount tokens to $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR for each user and rely on filesystem permissions to isolate access to each users' auth. For pure k8s API access, we generate a kubeconfig for these and make sure it's the first path in $KUBECONFIG, but this doesn't seem to work for Workload Identity.
